# Math opeartion across Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes, let's call them df A and df B

A =

```
0        1
123    798
456    845
789    932
```

B =

```
0        1
321    593
546    603
937    205
```

Now I would like to multiply them, but also with an expression, as in A-1/B^2 for each of them

AB =

```
0                1
123-1/(321^2)    798-1/(593^2)
456-1/(546^2)    845-1/603^2)
789-1/(937^2)    932-1/(205^2)
```

Now, I have figured I could loop through each row and each column and try some sort of
`A[i][j]-1/(B[i][j]^2)`
But when it goes up to a 1000x1000 matrix, it would take quite some time.

Is there any operation for pandas or numpy that allows these sort of cross matrix operations? Not just multiplying one matrix by the other, but rather doing a math opeartion between them.

Maybe calculate the divider at first for a new df B ?

Comment: Multiplication. addition, subtraction, and division are implemented as methods of `pd.DataFrame` and `pd.Series`, and between those objects and scalars. Play around with `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/`. Use `**` for exponentiation.

Comment: Thank you! I was too tired to realize, the ** for ^ solved it for me.